# timezonedb converting gmt_offset to +5:30 format?

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

this is the link i have  :

http://timezonedb.com/download

```
 timezone.csv
 Fields: "zone_id","abbreviation","time_start","gmt_offset","dst"


"370","CDT","-273686400","-18000","1"    
"370","EST","-266432400","-18000","0"
"370","EDT","-52938000","-14400","1"    
"370","EST","-37216800","-18000","0"
"370","EDT","-21488400","-14400","1"
"370","EST","-5767200","-18000","0"
"370","EDT","9961200","-14400","1"
"370","EST","25682400","-18000","0"
"370","EDT","41410800","-14400","1"
"370","EST","57736800","-18000","0"
```

as u can see, it gave time related data as some big number, how can i convert it to the format "utc+5:30" hours like that ....
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 3600 (number of seconds in an hour) to get the UTC offset in hours